# foreach trying to make 3 parameters

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is there a way I could make this happen? Its like foreach with 3 paramaters

Something like this

```
  foreach ($value as $v,$value2 as $v2,$value3 as $v3)

  <?php echo $v->name?>
  <?php echo $v->actual?>
  <?php echo $v2->estimated?>
  <?php echo $v3->projected?>
```

Comment: No. You should nest them.

Comment: How does your array (or object) look like? What does `print_r($value);` output? What's the expected result?

Comment: You can only loop over *one* array at a time.  Loop over one, then get the value at the same index from the other two.

Comment: Not really an answer, [Foreach Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) it only allows `$key` or `$key=>$value`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
foreach ($value as $v)
{
    foreach($value2 as $v2)
    {
         foreach($value3 as $v3)
         {
               echo $v->name;
               echo $v->actual;
               echo $v2->estimated;
               echo $v3->projected;
         }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($value as $v,$value2 as $v2,$value3 as $v3)
{
    echo $v->name;
    echo $v->actual;
}

foreach($value2 as $v2)
{
    echo $v2->projected;
}

foreach($value3 as $v3)
{
    echo $v3->estimated;
}
```

Which you may have known, but I don't think it's possible to actually put all three into one like you're asking.

EDIT: With a bit more information on what your `$value` arrays contain, it may be easier to provide you with a solution that can help you more easily accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve next elements from each array in every iteration:

```
do{
    $v = current($value);
    $v2 = current($value2);
    $v3 = current($value3);
    // ...
} while(next($value) !== false && next($value2) !== false && next($value3) !== false);
```

Assuming they have equal length, are not empty and contain no `false`s.

You may also want to use `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++){
    $v = $value[$i];
    $v2 = $value2[$i];
    $v3 = $value3[$i];
    // ...
}
```

Assuming their keys are numeric and they have equal length.